# How to start, detach and attach X applications on server

Tags: command-line, server, screen

After installing ubuntu-desktop on my server I can start a program with gui that runs on my server and forward the Screen to my local pc. I therefore use:

```
someuser@localhost:~$ ssh -X someuser@somehost
someuser@somehost:~$ gedit
```

I can also run, detach and attach command line based programs e.g. via [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) or [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). But how do I combine both, in case I want to run a GUI based program for a longer period of time on the server?

In that case I would like to have the graphical output of my program first on my local screen, start some process, than detach the graphical output from my local screen, logout from the server, let the program run, login to the server again and finally attach the graphical output to my local screen again.

Is that possible?

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not possible, only way is create a vncserver session or similar.

Comment: I'm not actually using gedit. this was just an example...

Comment: I am still of the opinion your method of server management is fundamentally flawed. Use the command line with tmux / screen or a web interface , a graphical DE has little or no place on a server and VNC is horribly insecure.

Comment: @Panther your comments are not really necessary, and do not help.

Comment: @dobey - I disagree, teaching people to securely manage servers is very helpful and web interfaces are, IMO, superior to any DE as the graphical interface is designed to manage various aspects of server management from any OS via a browser. You, of course, are free to your opinion as well.

Comment: @Panther You are making assumptions about the usage. The question mentions nothing about server management. You made that assumption on your own, and proceeded to rudely make comments based on it. The fact is, thin clients have been in use for decades, where everything is running on the server. The question is clear and does not mention any of the things you are making assumptions about.

Comment: @Panther. Surely you have a good point on the security aspects, however  you assume that my server is connected to the Internet and probably accessible to more people than just me, which is just not the case...

Comment: @joaoal I am glad you are interested in learning to manage servers. As a part of the learning process it would be helpful if you were open to learning new tricks. Empty your cup - http://wiki.c2.com/?EmptyYourCup . Part of my point is security, but my larger point is that there are far superior tools for managing a server than installing a desktop and VNC, and the web interfaces are very nice and will do what you want with great ease. You were willing to install an entire desktop and configure VNC, your cup is very full.

Comment: As far as security goes, I don't know why anyone would want to crack you, you have not posted much security information, and I have not performed any sort of security audit on your setup. However, I have seen a lot of full cups and your practices are some of the most common cracks I have seen, I would say installing a VNC server on Ubuntu is by far the most common reason I have seen people acquire an intruder. I have seen others mind you, but VNC is by far more common than other servers or vulnerabilities in the code.

Comment: @Panther, I am not sure that the OP is using VNC. Desktop and `ssh -X', yes, but maybe not VNC.

Comment: @Panther. My "server" is actually an old Desktop PC in my home network that I use to run a program with GUI that would take too long to process on my laptop. So there is really no big deal. However, I'm very grateful for your security advices and I also like (and get) the full cup analogy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Running GUI and text mode applications.

If you want to run several applications including a GUI application and a text mode application, I think you can do it like this,

- on the **console** (the monitor connected to the server) you run

  - the GUI applications 'directly' and
  - the text mode applications in terminal emulator windows.
- **remotely** you run

  - the GUI applications via `ssh -X` and
  - the text screen applications via `ssh`

  via separate terminal emulator windows in the client computer.

---

You cannot reconnect to a process with graphics (actively running graphics) like you describe in the question, but you can run a process in the background, and let it continue. You can test with the following command line. It will survive if you log out and and you will find it running when you log in again.

```
$ num=0;while true; do echo "$num";num=$((num+1));sleep 1;done > numbers &
```

Check with

```
$ tail -f numbers
```

### Security

Finally, if the server can be connected via the internet, or otherwise by several people via a LAN, please consider the security aspects with GUI connections raised by @Panther.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not really possible, as the way X11 functions does not permit disconnecting and reconnecting to the server, within a running app, in this way.

You can use something like RDP/VNC to run a full session on the server, where you can connect and disconnect to the RDP/VNC server from the client, leaving applications open and running on the remote server, which is actually more like how tmux/screen work than how ssh -X works.